# Chrome Browser does not render mobile site

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android

I use SAMSUNG GALAXY Y GT-S6312.

I was testing my site on google chrome for mobile view render. But it renders desktop site only

Tried clearing cache of browser. Stopped application. But no results.

Any Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Does Chrome render other websites in their "mobile" formats correctly?

If yes, you'd need to correctly configure your website (probably checking for user agent, and redirecting to mobile site) correctly, so as to render the mobile site.